# "If" statement with an optional value not working

Tags: swift, swift2

I have an `if` statement with a variable, however the `if` statement does not work correctly and I am guessing it is because of an optional value on the variable.

The statement goes something like this

```
If (x == 6) {

}
```

x does = 6 but I cannot get the if statement to work.

When I do a "print x", the result is

```
Optional("6")
```

So I know the number is 6 but it seems that the optional value is making this `if` statement not work. I cannot get this unwrapped so I'm looking for another option.

Comment: Habermas if let x = x where Int(x) == 6 { ... }

Answer (score 4):

See the double quotes? It means that `x` is `String` type not `Int`. You can do this way to make be more standard

```
if let x = x where x == "6" {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting:

```
Optional("6")
```

it means that the value is actually a string and not an int. If it was an int you would get:

```
Optional(6)
```

To double check you can try:

```
if x == "6"
{
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined `x` 
You’ll not get an optional if it is like

```
let x = 6 \\or var x = 6

if x == 6 {

print(x)

}
```

Will return you `6` not `Optional("6")`

Comment: Its a variable from a common class between view controllers

so when I call the variable is it like 

    (sharedData.x)

Comment: What’s the problem in unwrapping it, when you want to use it?

Comment: The class is setup like so

class SharedData {
    
    static let sharedInstance = SharedData()
    
    var x: String?
}

Comment: I changed something that made it unwrap so thats good. I still would like to know though why it won't work in a comparison when it is wrapped.

Comment: x is and optional, so you can’t compare it with a constant which is 6.